# Accurately Calculating the Memory used by a C++ Programming

Tags: c++, memory, sizeof

A program I am writing for work needs to keep track of the memory used by itself. But it can't monitor its memory usage as a whole, I need it to monitor each object in the program and how much memory that object is using, that way it can then tell that object to cut back on memory usage if it using above a certain capacity. The part that monitors memory usage holds a pointer to all created objects and keeps track of their memory usage by calling a method on that object that returns the size of the object.

The problem I'm having is that I cannot accurately calculate the size of the memory used. It doesn't matter if my calculation are off by a little bit but I'm getting big difference. The size that my program calculates varies (depending on which actions the program performs) between 1/2 to 2/3 of the actual memory usage of the program. For example a program that used 3.35gb of ram was calculated to only be using 2.16gb.

The current way I calculate the size of an object is by adding sizeof(*this) to the length of any vectors or arrays in the object multiplied by the sizeof the elements in the vector/array.

Is there something wrong with the way I'm calculating the memory used? Or is there just something else I'm not taking into account? If anyone knows of a program that you can analyse memory usage by different aspects of a program that would also be very helpful, that way I can track down where all this extra memory is coming from (preferably one that can run on Linux without GUI as I'm using Ubuntu server, but also have a windows machine I can use).

Comment: What objects do you keep in those vectors? If those objects allocate memory dynamically (using `new`, `malloc` and the like), `sizeof` won't account for the space consumed by this.

Comment: The problem probably comes from the program you are using to tell you how much memory has been allocated to your application (not your code doing the calculation). The problem is that this program is adding the sum of pages that have been assigned to your application by the OS. The runtime then does its own memory management using the pages allocated (not all the memory may be allocated to objects).

Comment: One simple thing: if a lot of your memory is in vectors, remember to use their capacity and not their size to estimate actual memory "usage" (i.e. occupation of virtual addresses) as opposed to theoretical memory usage (memory actually useful employed). Other containers are much more expensive because of container overhead (usually several pointers per element, which adds up fast when the elements are small objects like integer.)

Comment: In the vectors I calculated like this I am only holding primitive data types or structs containing primitive data types.

Comment: vectors are not problematic (but remember to use capacity, not size). By other containers I meant, for example, std::map, or even std::list.

Comment: If all you need is the total size of the program, then consider using a kernel API function. For example, getrlimit() can get you lots of information related memory limits of the program. Also, the files under `/proc/[pid]` for your program's pid will give you current stats for your program, see [here](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man5/proc.5.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there something wrong with the way I'm calculating the memory used?

Yes. First of all, the size of the memory consumed by your program may not be entirely used at any one point. For instance, after a vector resizes, the old memory block may be returned to the system. Or it may be held on to by the heap for the next time someone requests a memory block of the same size.

Also, do keep in mind that any libraries you are using (E.g. OS APIs) allocate memory, and those things aren't free.

Also keep in mind that there is additional overhead imposed by the heap manager for each memory allocation; usually on the order of a pointer or two, per allocation.

If you want to track what is using memory in your application, use a real memory profiler for that. If you want to dynamically scale how much memory your program allocates in the first place, use a profiler to figure out the average size taken up by one of the objects you are dealing with, and then limit by number of objects rather than memory size.

Comment: I had accounted that there would be some overhead so didn't expect to get an exact result. But I didn't realise memory blocks could be kept in the heap like that. That makes a lot of sense as to why my calculations are so different.